# Determining the order of a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}$$

where $n \geq 1$.

I see that the poles of $f$ are $i$ and $-i$. I've looked online and sources tell me that the pole $i$ is of order $n$, not of order $n+1$.

How precisely would I determine this order?

Comment: What are the sources that tell you so?

Comment: It was this link: http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/grads/clungstr/complex_analysis/pset4.pdf

However, I notice now that when they apply residue theorem, they do so assuming the order is $n + 1$, so their initial statement of the order being $n$ was probably a typo.

Comment: Then the problem is cleared. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as asking for the orders of the zeroes of the degree-$2(n + 1)$ polynomial
$$\frac{1}{f(x)} = (1 + z^2)^{n + 1}.$$
There are only two zeroes, $\pm i$, and since the coefficients are real, all zeroes come in complex conjugate pairs, so the zeroes of $\frac{1}{f}$ (and hence the poles of $f$) at $i$ and $-i$ both have order $n + 1$